# EditText in a DialogFragment hides it's value when it gets focus

Tags: android, xamarin.android, android-edittext, android-9.0-pie

After updating the target version of the Xamarin.Android app to Android 9 and the mobile device to Android 9, I've seen a weird behaviour on an EditText in a DialogFragment. When the dialog opens, the EditText requests focus allowing the user to type into it. But since I've updated the version to 9, the EditText seems to hide the value which was in the EditText field until I press a key on the keyboard.

I have added the below lines to my AndroidManifest file but without a resolution:

```
android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

I have also tried giving the text size a lower pixel size and increased the height of the EditText just to triple check. But this did nothing.

Now if I create an emulator with an OS of 7.1 and build the app to target 7.1, it works as expected without hiding the value until a keypress.

Adding Layout xml file for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_gravity="right|center"
        android:id="@+id/delete"
        android:src="@drawable/delete_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <EditText
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:maxLength="13"
        android:inputType="number"
        android:layout_width="210dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/bEdit"
        android:layout_column="1"
        android:hint="B" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/bError"
    android:visibility="gone">
    <TextView
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@color/munster_red"
        android:text="Error: Invalid B"
        android:textSize="17dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_column="1" />
</LinearLayout>
<TableLayout
    android:gravity="center"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="15dp">
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Unit: "
            android:layout_gravity="right|center" />
        <TextView
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/unitNumber" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
            android:text="Tag: "
            android:layout_gravity="right|center" />
        <EditText
            android:textSize="28dp"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tagEdit"
            android:maxLength="5" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/checkedTextView1"
            android:text="Y:"
            android:layout_gravity="right|center" />
        <EditText
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLength="4"
            android:id="@+id/yEdit" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:id="@+id/yieldError"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/yMessage"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/red"
            android:text="Warning: Y out of Range"
            android:textSize="15dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_column="1" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_gravity="left|center"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </TableRow>
    <LinearLayout
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:text="Cancel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/cancel" />
        <Button
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_button"
            android:text="Missed Y"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/mYield"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
        <Button
            android:layout_margin="2dp"
            android:padding="12dp"
            android:background="@drawable/green_button_inactive"
            android:text="Save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:textColor="@color/green"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TableLayout>
```

Has anyone had something similar?

--- EDIT

I have also copy and pasted the EditText which is causing the issue and pasted it under the issued one. The problem went away and acted as usual. It's very strange and only started happening after the upgrade, no changes were made to the layout previously or the code.

[image: image showing the input hiding the value]

Comment: According to your description, you mean that virtual keyboard will hide edit text? I run your code but I don't find this problem, can you provide one screenshot about problem?

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT - I've added an image. The keyboard isn't hiding the edit text at all. The red circle you can see the value hides.

Comment: I run you project, the editText can display value correctly, please see the screenshot:[EditText display value](https://github.com/CherryBu/gif/blob/master/Image%2010.png), if you still have problem, please provide your sample at github, I will download your sample to test.

Comment: @CherryBu-MSFT did you put the layout into a DialogFragment though? From the looks of your image, it looks like just a normal layout? Mine is in a dialog fragment. I tried running in an emulator also on Android 9 and the issue happens there too.

Comment: can you provide one sample at github that can reproduce this problem?